# ARRAffinity Cookie How to Set SameSite Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, web-config

I had security vulnerability popped up for one of the websites.
vulnerability is Insecure Cookie Configuration - SameSite Flag.
After trying and analysing solutions i saw that only ARRAffinity is having Samesite attribute not set.
I found the following solution for setting ARRAffinity cookie's SameSite attribute in web.config file

```
    <system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
      <rule name="Add SameSite Cookie Flag to ArrAffinity cookie" enabled="true">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{R:0}" pattern="ARRAffinity=(.*)" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
          <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 
          10_14.+Version/.*Safari" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
          <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="CPU iPhone OS 12" ignoreCase="true" 
          negate="true" />
          <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="iPad; CPU OS 12" ignoreCase="true" 
          negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_COOKIE};Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;secure" />
      </rule>
    </outboundRules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

But after this website is showing two ARRAffinity Cookies one with SameSite=None other with SameSite still empty.Users are also having Sign-in issues because of this. How can i fix this? If not ,then is there any other way i can set-up SameSite attribute for ARRAffinity?